# how to copy a file from application bundle to documents directory in ios using monotouch

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I'm impementing tesseract ocr in monotouch.I want to convert the following code in c#.

```
// Set up the tessdata path. This is included in the application bundle
// but is copied to the Documents directory on the first run.
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = ([documentPaths count] > 0) ? [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

NSString *dataPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tessdata"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
// If the expected store doesn't exist, copy the default store.
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]) {
    // get the path to the app bundle (with the tessdata dir)
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *tessdataPath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tessdata"];
    if (tessdataPath) {
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:tessdataPath toPath:dataPath error:NULL];
    }
}

setenv("TESSDATA_PREFIX", [[documentPath stringByAppendingString:@"/"] UTF8String], 1);
```

I don't know how convert the above code into c#.kindly help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get to the documents folder you can use:

```
string docPath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

To manage files in there, you can use the normal System.IO methods. Like creating folders/files, etc.